# Data Scraping from txt file with consistent structure

Tags: python, excel, database, text, screen-scraping

I'm working with a very old program that outputs the results for a batch query in a very odd format (at least for me).
Imagine having queried info for the objects `A`, `B` and `C`.
The output will look like this:

```
name : A
------
Group 1 
  p1 : 11
  p2 : 12

Group 2
  p3 : 23
  p4 : 24


======

name : B
------
Group 1 
  p1 : 11
  p2 : 12

Group 2
  p3 : 23
  p4 : 24

======

name : C
------
Group 1 
  p1 : 11
  p2 : 12

Group 2
  p3 : 23
  p4 : 24
```

Do you have any idea of how to put the data in a more useful format?
A possible good format would be a table with columns A B C and rows p1, p2...

I had few ideas but I don't really know how to implement those:

1. Every object is separated by a `======` string, that means i can use this to separate in many .txt files the output
2. Then I can read the files with excel setting `:` as separator, obtaining a csv file with 2 columns (1 containing the p descriptors and one with the actual values)
3. Now i need to merge all the csv files into one single csv with as many columns as objects and `px` rows

I'd like to do this in python but I really don't know any package for this situation. Also the objects are a few hundreds so I need an automatized algorithm for doing that.

Any tip, advice or idea you can think of is welcome.

Comment: to better understand the data, here are some questions:  

1. you're not interested in the groups? i.e. group1/2 in the example doesn't matter?  
2. will the data actually be labelled with the enumerable p1...x?  
3. otherwise, is it important to record the labels p1..x ?  
4. is it ensured that data will follow the same format for each main entry A,B, or could there be a missing p3 somewhere?

Comment: also, is the expected output a csv file to read into Excel, or which will be the intended processing? Possibly also in python? Pandas dataframes which you might be familiar with provides a great tool to do sums, find max values, statistics etc for data.

Comment: 1) not interested in the groups; 2,3) i do need the labels p1... px so that i can later extract (using pandas for example) all p1 variables for all objects; 4) The text output has always the same structure, but sometimes the value for the corresponding key is missing and it will be replaced by some string stating that the data is missing.

Comment: hi! as the p1..px keys will always be present/the structure stays the same, it seems my solution would still work, but would just save the "missing-value-string". For the keys, you'd need to record them for the first item and then use them as column labels in csv or df, which way you choose to save the result.

It'd be a good idea to make a couple of small test inputs to run thru to ensure correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution putting the data you say you need - not all labels - in a csv file. Each output line starts with the name A/B/C and then comes the values p1..x.

It has no handling of missing values, so in that case just the present values will be listed, thus column 5 will not always be p4. It relies on the assumption that there's a *name* line starting every item/entry, and that all other a:b lines have a value b to be stored. This should be a good start to put it into another structure should you need so. The format is truly special, more of a report structure, so I'd guess there's no suitable general purpose lib. Flat format is another similarly tricky old format type for which there are libraries - I've used it when calculating how much money each swedish participator in the interrail program should receive. Tricky business but fun! :-)

The code:

```
import re
import csv

with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

entries = []
entry = []
for line in lines:
    parts = re.split(r':', line)
    if len(parts) >= 2:
        label = parts[0]
        value = parts[1].strip()
        if label.startswith('name'):
            print('got name: ' + value)
            # start new entry with the name as first value
            entry = [value]
            entries.append(entry)
        else:
            print('got value: ' + value)
            entry.append(value)     

print('collected {} entries'.format(len(entries)))


with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
    wr = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerows(entries)
```